# figure positioning

Tags: floats, positioning

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Local Analysis: Steady State A}

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=70mm]{local_Analysis.jpg}
    \caption{Local Analysis}
    \label{local_analysis_A}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see the figure is after the `\subsection` command, but when i compile my document it appears before the subsection. Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: `figure`s float. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) for 'the full story'.